# Japanese live-action anthology film featuring boy with saucepan lid over hole in chest

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a Japanese film I watched on television about 8 or so years ago, which may have been a stand-alone film or a compilation of short films.

I don't remember a lot about the details of it but each short film was quite different in style and tone.

There was one story about a young man (played by a child actor, if I remember correctly) who wore colourful clothes and a saucepan lid over his chest to cover a hole in in heart.

There was another story about a man who provided dating advice to other men over the phone and danced energetically between phone calls.

Possibly another one about a ninja?

I have had no luck searching for this film using keyword searches. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall what channel you saw this on?   Were all of the segments animated?

Comment: Hi Dave, I don't know if I helps but I saw it on an Australian free-to-air channel called SBS. The channel specialises in foreign television and cinema. If I remember correctly it was entirely live-action, however there may have been some partially animated scenes. My guess would be that the film is roughly from the 90s or early 00s.

Comment: Any information is potentially useful; I don't know about SBS, but people here have managed to dig up records of what what was televised on other channels.  You never know.